# Choosing between HTML5 <audio> tag and Soundmanager2

Tags: html, audio-streaming, html5-audio, soundmanager2

I am redesigning a music player. It currently uses Soundmanager2 V2.97a.20110801. But now since the HTML5  is so easy to use, is there much of a reason why I should continue using Soundmanager2? Or are there advantages to it that I am unaware of? Could you possibly help with a simple compare and contrast of the 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soundmanager uses flash, HTML5 audio uses the native capabilities of the browser. A pitfall with `<audio>` is that you'll have to encode your audio at least twice, as mp3 and ogg.

Another thing is that older browsers, IE8 in particular, don't support `<audio>`. You may want to [detect](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#video)* audio support, and, if not, fall back to Soundmanager.

- [About audio codecs](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#audio-codecs)

  - This web page talks about `<video>`, but detecting `<audio>` is done almost the same way.

Comment: actually soundmanager only uses flash as a fallback - most browsers today don't need to use the flash fallback but still enough formats (like mp3 in firefox) still depend on it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

the HTML5 audio tag is still a work in progress and unfortunately still has too many browser specific differences in supported audio formats for an easy cross browser solution.

it still varies widely depending upon what you want to accomplish.

here is a link to the info you should read through:
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/getstarted/#intro

---

this may be a little off topic but i built an opensource audio library on github for playing multichannel sounds like this...

```
// play the lowest piano key (1)
jThump( 1, 'piano' );

// play the highest piano key (88)
jThump( 88, 'piano' );
```

below is a simple demo that plays random notes when you press the 'z' key

http://jthump.com